# Cone and Dual Cone in $\mathbb{R}^2$ space

Tags: convex-analysis, dual-cone, convex-cone

Boyd's book, my understanding of cone and dual cone for 2-space is: 
If we think of a circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ space, cone $K$ and dual cone $K^*$ would be like this:

[image]

Here, $K^* = y | x^Ty \geq 0 \text{ for all } x \in K$

Now question is: How do you draw cone and dual cone for these:

1. $K = \{ (a_1, a_2) \in \mathbb{R} | |a_1| \leq a_2 \}$
2. $ K = \{ Ax | x \geq 0 \}$

I am just trying to get an intuitive idea about the geometry of the cones and dual cones.

Comment: Usually, cones extend to infinity and are not bounded by a circle.  Also, the definition that I typically use for dual cone results in a different region than what you have highlighted.  Perhaps you could provide some additional background.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is wrong.  Consider the vector $x=(1,1)$ and the vector $y=(-1,-1)$.  $x$ is clearly in $K$.  You claim that $y$ is in $K^{*}$, but $x^{T}y=-2<0$.  In fact, the dual of the positive orthant $R^{n}_{+}$ is $R^{n}_{+}$.

Comment: I have updated the picture. Do you think it's right now?

Comment: No, it's still not correct.  Keep in mind that $K^{*}$ is the set of $y$ such that $x^{T}y\geq 0$ *for all* $x$ in $K$.  That means that $y$ must be within 90 degrees of *every* vector $x$ in $K$.

Comment: my understanding is, we can find hyperplanes which supports cone $K$ and those hyperpalnes goes through the 2nd and 4th quardent.(?). Could you please sketch the correct one? What about the other two?